# Need to have 2 different div stretched to the screen with one div in center

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to achieve following structure.

http://s15.postimg.org/aeno9dpmz/screen_shot.jpg

What I have done so far is [this](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dqAbH).

I have tried to set the two div's on the side with width in `%` and middle div with `width: 300px` all three div have `float:left`

The issue I am facing is

- space on the right for large screen
- last div falls down for small screen.

I would only prefer `<div>` not `<table>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to Add few more div's inside right and left div 
and set the outer div to `width: 50%;`

And keep the middle content in center with `margin: 0 auto`
and pulling it down with minus margin

```css
.container {
  background: #ccc;
}

.outerWrap {
  background: #dfdfdf;
  padding: 20px 0;
}

.rightCnt,
.leftCnt {
  width: 50%
}

.innerCnt {
  background: #2a4675;
  color: #fff;
}

.leftCnt .innerCnt {
  text-align: right
}

.rightCnt .innerCnt {
  background: #072a26;
}

.rightCnt .innerCnt {
  margin-left: 170px
}

.leftCnt .innerCnt {
  margin-right: 170px
}

.txtCnt {
  min-height: 60px;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 280px
}

.midCnt {
  width: 300px;
  margin: -10px auto -90px;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  min-height: 80px
}
```

```html
<link href="https://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="cntOne">
  <div class="container">
    <ul>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
      <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
      <li>Vestibulum auctor dapibus neque.</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="outerWrap clearfix">
  <div class="midCnt">
    <p>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="leftCnt pull-left">
    <div class="innerCnt clearfix">
      <div class="txtCnt pull-right">
        <p>Vestibulum auctor dapibus neque.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="rightCnt pull-left">
    <div class="innerCnt clearfix">
      <div class="txtCnt pull-left">
        <p>Vestibulum auctor dapibus neque.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="cntOne">
  <div class="container">
    <ul>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
      <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
      <li>Vestibulum auctor dapibus neque.</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

keeping the rules in percent seems to work for me:

```
.midCnt {
  width: 36%;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 2%;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  min-height: 80px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

[UPDATED CODE](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/renbG)

is this what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

By using CSS3 `Flex method` you can achieve the desire result. See the **[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/zujamado/1/edit)** First.

**HTML Code is like this.**

```
<div class="flex">
    <div>uno</div>
    <div>due</div>
    <div>tre</div>
  </div>
```

**CSS Code is here**

```
.flex
   {
      /* basic styling */
      width: 100%;
      height: 200px;
      border: 1px solid #555;
      font: 14px Arial;
      /* flexbox setup */
      display: -webkit-flex;
      -webkit-flex-direction: row;
justify-content: center;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
   }
   .flex > div
   {
      -webkit-flex: 1 1 auto;
      flex: 1 1 auto;
      width: 30px; 
   }

   /* colors */
   .flex > div:nth-child(1){ background : #009246; }
   .flex > div:nth-child(2){ background : #F1F2F1; }
   .flex > div:nth-child(3){ background : #CE2B37; }
```